# Mirror Lamps on x axis

Tags: mirror

Does anyone know how to mirror lamps on the x axis, like a mirror modifier would for a mesh? I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, and it did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it manually with a duplicate lamp:

- <kbd>Space</kbd>, Snap Cursor to Center, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Set the pivot center in the toolbar on the bottom to 3D Cursor
- Select your lamp, <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Done.

If the lamp is changing position more often, duplicate it and add an object constraint:

- Select the dupli lamp
- Properties, Constraints, Add Object Constraint, Copy Location
- Check Invert for the axis you want to mirror.
- For directional lamps, also try Copy Rotation

Comment: For future reference, you can press CTRL + C to snap the cursor to the centre.

Comment: Did you mean Shift + C? I didn't write that beacuse it also changes the camera position and I don't like that

Comment: Whoops,  Shift + C is what i meant! Sorry. Anyway i suppose it does do that but if i do some digging i may find a version that snaps it to the centre without moving the camera.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do this with multiple lamps and am trying to copy their respective rotation, mirrored on the x axis.  Is there a quick way to do this. The above suggestion did not mirror the rotation.

Comment: The constraintsecond do, but I'd rather not do constraints for each lamp.

Comment: @JonathanYanke you can copy constraints from one lamp to all others [with Copy Constraints To Selected Objects operator](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/add-object-constraint-to-a-number-of-selected-objects)

Answer (score 2):

For x-axis mirror, invert lamp YZ-rotation signs,  plus to minus and minus to plus.