# Copy Loc/Rot constraints of all bones with same name across 2 armatures?

Tags: animation, scripting

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated. I'm working with a difficult armature I need to animate. The mocap/animation plugin doesn't seem to be behaving well with this specific armature. The only thing I've found that works reliably is copying loc/rot constraints from source to target armature. It is incredibly tedious. Bone names are identical across both armatures, is there a way to automate this process instead of going through each bone individually and selection loc/rot? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/add-object-constraint-to-a-number-of-selected-objects

Comment: Thanks but this topic deals with objects and not bones, I need a method of  saving and applying a batch of bone constraints to another armature.

Comment: but the constraint from armature number one will reference to bones from armature number one...Do you want bones from armature1 to control bones in armature2? Perhaps you can simply duplicate the original armature and parent it to the second character.