# How to apply bone constraints and object constraints to the instances of my object?

Tags: bones, constraints, instances

## Context

I am using the CarRigPro addon in which I can chose the object that the car suspensions are simulated on.
For that, I add my object (Ground) as the target for both a bone constraint, and an object constraint as shown below.

[image: Bone constraint]

---

[image]

## Problem

I would like to create many instances (Add -> Collection instance) of that Ground object, so I would like the constraints to work on these instances as well. However that doesn't work.

How can I make this ?

Comment: hello, could you please show a screenshot so that we understand what is the situation exactly?

Comment: Hello @moonboots , thank you for the reply, I updated the question.

Comment: When you say 'instance', do you mean copies created by, for instance, an array modifier, linked duplication or object instancing, or do you mean different ground objects that are independent of each other?  I assume the later?

Comment: In the second case, does the answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/add-object-constraint-to-a-number-of-selected-objects) work for you?

Comment: @MartyFouts I edited the question again, what I mean is collection instances (Add -> Collection instance). Because they all need to be a duplication of that first Ground object so that editing it will edit the rest of them.

Comment: @MartyFouts I suppose I could work around this by using the solution in that other thread you've linked by copy/pasting instead of instancing, and only doing so once I am finished and then apply the constraints. It would not be as practical but if there isn't a better way, I will go for this.

Comment: I hope there's a better way and you get an answer, but alas, the mass copy is the only way I know.  It should work for collection instancing as well.